# Copy an .xcdatamodeld file from Objective-C project to Swift project

Tags: xcode, core-data

I have an Objective-C project and I want to create the same project in Swift. Can I copy my .xcdatamodeld file from the Objective-C project to the Swift project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The model file is language-independent, so **yes**, you can copy it to another project.

By the way, Objective-C and Swift is interchangeable in one project, so it's not a must to create a separate project for Swift code only.